# Keep Checkboxes checked after failed form submission

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

I have looked thru many of the similar questions, but I am still having an issue with being able to keep my checkbox selections after the submit and validation. I have the checkboxes set as an array, and I need to keep them this way for submission to my database later. I know my array is being populated because I do some debugging at the end and my imploded "string version" contains the array data as it should.

PHP Validation Code (piece as it pertains to my array).

```
    <?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $serviceAttendedErr = $serviceAttendedErrClass = $firstNameErr = $firstNameErrClass = $lastNameErr = $lastNameErrClass = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = $checkedTermsErr = "";
    $name = $email = $gender = $classes = $myDateTime = $course = $checkedTerms = $successMessage = $string_version_serviceAttended = "";
    $serviceAttended = [];
    //$errors = 0;

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $myDateTime = date('m/d/Y g:i a');
    //$errors = $_POST["submit"]; // Resetting this variable for each submit of the form

    // making sure someone doesn't just add white spaces into the input field to bypass the validation
    $firstName = test_input($_POST["firstName"]);
    $lastName = test_input($_POST["lastName"]);

    if (!empty($_POST["serviceAttended"])){
        $serviceAttended = $_POST["serviceAttended"];
        //Making a string version of the above array so it can be used for debug on the screen
        $string_version_serviceAttended = implode(',', $serviceAttended);
    }

    // Checking to make sure at least one service button has been chosen, 
    // can also specify a particular one is needed as well (see isChecked Function)
        if(isChecked('serviceAttended','')) { 
            $serviceAttendedErrClass = " alert alert-success";
        } else { 
            $serviceAttendedErr = " <h5>Please Choose At Least One!</h5>";
            $serviceAttendedErrClass = " alert alert-danger";
        }
```

HTML Checkbox (Note: I am using bootstrap for formatting)

```
<div class="form-group row">

        <div class="col-12 card card-block requiredIcon <?php echo $serviceAttendedErrClass; ?>">
            <div class = "text-danger offset-5"><?php echo $serviceAttendedErr;?></div>
            <div class="btn-group offset-1" data-toggle="buttons" for="serviceAttended[]">

                <label class="form-check-label text-left mx-2">When Did You Attended?</label>

                <label class="col-2 btn btn-secondary btn-responsive not-active">   
                    <input name="serviceAttended[]" type="checkbox" value="8am" <?php if(isset($serviceAttended) && is_array($serviceAttended) && in_array('8am', $serviceAttended)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> > 8:00 AM
                </label>
                <label class="col-2 btn btn-secondary btn-responsive not-active">
                    <input name="serviceAttended[]" type="checkbox" value="930am" <?php if(isset($_POST['serviceAttended']) && is_array($_POST['serviceAttended']) && in_array('930am', $_POST['serviceAttended'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> > 9:30 AM
                </label>
                <label class="col-2 btn btn-secondary btn-responsive not-active">
                    <input name="serviceAttended[]" type="checkbox" value="11am" <?php if(isset($_POST['serviceAttended']) && is_array($_POST['serviceAttended']) && in_array('11am', $_POST['serviceAttended'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> > 11:00 AM
                </label>
                <label class="col-2 btn btn-secondary btn-responsive not-active">
                    <input name="serviceAttended[]" type="checkbox" value="other" <?php if(isset($_POST['serviceAttended']) && is_array($_POST['serviceAttended']) && in_array('other', $_POST['serviceAttended'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> > Other
                </label>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

As you can see I have tried both the variable assigned $serviceAttended and the raw _$POST['serviceAttended']. But I get the same result.

What am I missing in my in-line PHP statement to get the button/checkbox(s) to remain checked after the submit and validation?

I have tried all of your solutions below and none seem to work. Maybe this isn't an issue with the in-line php. Maybe it has something to do with the php to bootstrap interactions. In any case I have included the entire html form below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Optional meta tags --> 
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="signin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
</script>



<style>



.btn-responsive {
    white-space: normal !important;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.requiredIcon  {  
     background: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fugue/icon/asterisk-small.png) no-repeat;
     background-position:right top;
}


:required  {  
     background: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fugue/icon/asterisk-small.png) no-repeat;
     background-position:right top;
}


</style>



<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$serviceAttendedErr = $serviceAttendedErrClass = $firstNameErr = $firstNameErrClass = $lastNameErr = $lastNameErrClass = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = $checkedTermsErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $classes = $myDateTime = $course = $checkedTerms = $successMessage = $string_version_serviceAttended = "";
$serviceAttended = [];
//$errors = 0;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

$myDateTime = date('m/d/Y g:i a');
//$errors = $_POST["submit"]; // Resetting this variable for each submit of the form

// making sure someone doesn't just add white spaces into the input field to bypass the validation
$firstName = test_input($_POST["firstName"]);
$lastName = test_input($_POST["lastName"]);

if (!empty($_POST["serviceAttended"])){
    $serviceAttended = $_POST["serviceAttended"];
    //Making a string version of the above array so it can be used for debug on the screen
    $string_version_serviceAttended = implode(',', $serviceAttended);
}

// Checking to make sure at least one service button has been chosen, 
// can also specify a particular one is needed as well (see isChecked Function)
    if(isChecked('serviceAttended','')) { 
        $serviceAttendedErrClass = " alert alert-success";
    } else { 
        $serviceAttendedErr = " <h5>Please Choose At Least One!</h5>";
        $serviceAttendedErrClass = " alert alert-danger";
    } 

// First Name Checks
    if (empty($firstName)){
        $firstNameErr = " (Required!)";
        $firstNameErrClass = " alert alert-danger";

//      $errors = 1;
    }else {
        $firstName = test_input($firstName);
        $firstNameErrClass = " alert alert-success";
    }   

// Last Name Checks 
    if (empty($lastName)){
        $lastNameErr = " (Required!)";
        $lastNameErrClass = " alert alert-danger";

//      $errors = 1;
    }else {
        $lastName = test_input($lastName);
        $lastNameErrClass = " alert alert-success";
    }   

// Email Address Checks 
    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
//      $errors = 1;
    }else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
//          $errors = 1;
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["course"])) {
        $course = "";
    }else {
        $course = test_input($_POST["course"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["classes"])) {
        $classes = "";
    }else {
        $classes = test_input($_POST["classes"]);
    }
    if (!isset($_POST["gender"])){  
        $genderErr = "Gender is required";
//      $errors = 1;
    }else {
        $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
    }
    if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
        $subjectErr = "You must select 1 or more";
//      $errors = 1;
    }else {
        $subject = $_POST["subject"];   
    }

    if (!isset($_POST["checkedTerms"])){
        $checkedTermsErr = "You must accept the Terms of use";
//      $errors = 1;
    }else {
        $checkedTerms = test_input($_POST["checkedTerms"]); 
    }

//  if($errors == 0){
//      $successMessage ="Form Submitted Successfully..."; // IF no errors
//  }
}

// Function to remove useless info from the inputs
function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

function isChecked($chkname,$value) { 
    if(!empty($_POST[$chkname]) && !empty($value)) {
        foreach($_POST[$chkname] as $chkval) { 
            if($chkval == $value) { 
                return true; 
            } 
        } 
    }else {
        if(!empty($_POST[$chkname])) {  
            return true; 
        }
    }
    return false; 
}

// Original "isChecked()" function
//function isChecked($chkname,$value) { 
//  if(!empty($_POST[$chkname])) {
//      foreach($_POST[$chkname] as $chkval) { 
//          if($chkval == $value) { 
//              return true; 
//          } 
//      } 
//  } 
//  return false; 
//}


?>








</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

        <!-- Use the container for testing screen size only. Remove it later -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="hidden-lg-down"><span class="badge badge-default">xl</span></div>
            <div class="hidden-md-down hidden-xl-up"><span class="badge badge-default">lg</span></div>
            <div class="hidden-sm-down hidden-lg-up"><span class="badge badge-default">md</span></div>
            <div class="hidden-xs-down hidden-md-up"><span class="badge badge-default">sm</span></div>
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm-up"><span class="badge badge-default">xs</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-4 offset-4 text-center">
            <h2>Header Text</h2>
        </div>

    </div>

    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method = "POST" action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

        <div class="form-group row">

            <div class="col-12 card card-block requiredIcon <?php echo $serviceAttendedErrClass; ?>">
                <div class = "text-danger offset-5"><?php echo $serviceAttendedErr;?></div>
                <div class="btn-group offset-1" data-toggle="buttons" for="serviceAttended">

                    <label class="form-check-label text-left mx-2">When Did You Attended?</label>

                    <label class="col-2 btn btn-secondary btn-responsive not-active">   
                        <input name="serviceAttended[]" type="checkbox" value="8am" <?php if(isset($_POST['serviceAttended']) && in_array('8am', $_POST['serviceAttended'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> > 8:00 AM
                    </label>
                    <label class="col-2 btn btn-secondary btn-responsive not-active">
                        <input name="serviceAttended[]" type="checkbox" value="930am" <?php if(isset($_POST['serviceAttended']) && in_array('930am', $_POST['serviceAttended'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> > 9:30 AM
                    </label>
                    <label class="col-2 btn btn-secondary btn-responsive not-active">
                        <input name="serviceAttended[]" type="checkbox" value="11am" <?php if(isset($_POST['serviceAttended']) && in_array('11am', $_POST['serviceAttended'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> > 11:00 AM
                    </label>
                    <label class="col-2 btn btn-secondary btn-responsive not-active">
                        <input name="serviceAttended[]" type="checkbox" value="other" <?php if(isset($_POST['serviceAttended']) && is_array($_POST['serviceAttended']) && in_array('other', $_POST['serviceAttended'])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> > Other
                    </label>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-2 card card-block">

                <label class="form-check-label py-2">Button Column</label>

                <div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons" for="inputMemberStatus">


                    <label class=" btn btn-secondary btn-responsive not-active">
                        <input name="inputMemberStatus" id="optionOne" name="optionOne" type="radio"> Option One
                    </label>

                    <label class=" btn btn-secondary btn-responsive not-active">
                        <input name="inputMemberStatus" id="optionTwo" name="optionTwo" type="radio"> Option Two
                    </label>

                    <label class=" btn btn-secondary btn-responsive not-active">
                        <input name="inputMemberStatus" id="optionThree" name="optionThree" type="radio"> Option Three
                    </label>

                    <label class=" btn btn-secondary btn-responsive not-active">
                        <input name="inputMemberStatus" id="optionFour" name="optionFour" type="radio"> Option Four
                    </label>

                    <label class=" btn btn-secondary btn-responsive not-active">
                        <input name="inputMemberStatus" id="optionFive" name="optionFive" type="radio"> Option Five
                    </label>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-10 card card-block">

                <label class="form-check-label py-2">My Contact Information</label>       

                <div class="form-group row" id="userNameInfo">

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input class="form-control <?php echo $firstNameErrClass; ?>" id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name <?php echo $firstNameErr;?>" <?php if (!empty($_POST['firstName'])) {echo "value=\"" . $firstName . "\"";} ?> required="required">
<!--                            <div class = "text-danger">* <?php echo $firstNameErr;?></div> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input class="form-control <?php echo $lastNameErrClass; ?>" id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name <?php echo $lastNameErr;?>" <?php if (!empty($_POST['lastName'])) {echo "value=\"" . $lastName . "\"";} ?> required="required">
<!--                            <div class = "text-danger">* <?php echo $lastNameErr;?></div> -->
                    </div>

                </div>


                <!-- This Code Section Not Used at this time
                <div class="form-group row px-3" data-toggle="button">

                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input name="updateMyInfo" class="form-check-input" type="button" value="Please Update My Information" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#userAddressInfo">
                    </label>

                </div>


                <div class="collapse" id="userAddressInfo">
        -->

                <div id="userAddressInfo">

                    <div class="form-group addressInfo row">

                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input class="form-control" id="userAddress1" name="userAddress1" type="text" placeholder="Address Line 1">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input class="form-control" id="userAddress2" name="userAddress2" type="text" placeholder="Address Line 2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <input class="form-control" id="userCity" name="userCity" type="text" placeholder="City">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <select class="form-control" id="userState" name="userState" placeholder="State">
                                <option value="  ">State</option>
                                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                                <option value="CA">California</option>
                                <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                                <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                                <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                                <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                                <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                                <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                                <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                                <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                                <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                                <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                                <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                                <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                                <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                                <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                                <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                                <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                                <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                                <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                                <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                                <option value="NY">New York</option>
                                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                                <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                                <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                                <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                                <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                                <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                                <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                                <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                                <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                                <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <input class="form-control" id="userZip" name="userZip" type="text" placeholder="Zip Code">
                        </div>

                        <div class="row col-12 py-2">
                            <!-- For Row Spacing use ONLY -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-12">
                            <input class="form-control" id="userEmail" name="userEmail" type="text" placeholder="E-Mail">
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row card card-block">


            <div class="form-group">

                <div class="col-12">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="userComment" name="userComment" placeholder="Comments" rows="5"></textarea>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row card card-block">

            <div class="form-group">

                <div class="col-6 offset-3 text-center py-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </form>
</div>







</br>
</br>
<?php
echo "<h3>Your given values are as :</h3>";
echo ("<p>Your Date Applied is: $myDateTime</p>");
echo ("<p>Your Service Attended is: "); if(!empty($string_version_serviceAttended)){ echo ("$string_version_serviceAttended</p>");}
echo ("<p>Your First Name is: "); if(!empty($firstName)){ echo ("$firstName</p>");}
echo ("<p>Your Last Name is: "); if(!empty($lastName)){ echo ("$lastName</p>");}

//echo ("<p> your email address is: $email</p>");
//echo ("<p>Your class time at: $course</p>");
//echo ("<p>your class info: $classes </p>");
//echo ("<p>your gender is: $gender</p>");
//echo ("<p>your Terms Checked: $checkedTerms</p>");

?>








<!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Please note: 
I am working my way down the form adding the validations as I go. So the form itself is complete and functional, but much of the form checking is still not complete.

Comment: do you mean the default state of the check box should be checked?

Comment: try my answer @Akintunde

Comment: @caclark the pending edit: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16104617 was that part of your original code but had trouble with the paste? I hope you haven't left the question and you need to respond to comments and answers given.

Comment: I am not sure where the pending edit came from. I only had the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a condition inside the checkbox to check if the checkbox was checked if was checked then mark it as checked

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxname" value="value" <?php if(isset($_POST['checkboxname'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  />
```

Comment: How it will work for multiple checkboxes with the same name?

Comment: why did you reject the edit? http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16104617

Comment: @Fred-ii- because from my side I did not see any html form provided by the OP.  so aint sure where did Amit get that form as the OP did not even comment, where we would say its from the comments

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Ok. Well, I'll check it out to see if it was part of the OP's original code (or not). If it wasn't, I'll do a rollback and advise the person who made the edit.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Update: [Amit said it was part of their code...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43935825/keep-checkboxes-checked-after-failed-form-submission#comment74905547_43936170).

Comment: @Fred-ii- well could not see that in the original code, even though I checked multiple times, even now as I'm speaking to you.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile This `"> When Did You Attended? > 8:00 AM > 9:30 AM > 11:00 AM > Other` is (usuall)y  a sign of unindented code. When in doubt (before an edit), go into "edit mode" yourself and you stand to see unindented code ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned checkbox is array use `in_array('2',$_POST['checkboxname'])` like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="serviceAttended[]" value="2" <?php if(isset($_POST['checkboxname']) && in_array('2',$_POST['checkboxname'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  />

<input type="checkbox" name="serviceAttended[]" value="3" <?php if(isset($_POST['checkboxname']) && in_array('3',$_POST['checkboxname'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  />
```

Comment: this is innovative. `+1`

Comment: *"this is innovative. +1"* - @Akintunde what +1? there's no upvote here.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the keys for your checkbox elements like below:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-12 card card-block requiredIcon <?php echo $serviceAttendedErrClass; ?>">
        <div class = "text-danger offset-5"><?php echo $serviceAttendedErr;?></div>
        <div class="btn-group offset-1" data-toggle="buttons" for="serviceAttended[]">

            <label class="form-check-label text-left mx-2">When Did You Attended?</label>

            <label class="col-2 btn btn-secondary btn-responsive not-active">   
                <input name="serviceAttended[0]" type="checkbox" value="8am" <?php if(isset($_POST['serviceAttended'][0])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> > 8:00 AM
            </label>
            <label class="col-2 btn btn-secondary btn-responsive not-active">
                <input name="serviceAttended[1]" type="checkbox" value="930am" <?php if(isset($_POST['serviceAttended'][1])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> > 9:30 AM
            </label>
            <label class="col-2 btn btn-secondary btn-responsive not-active">
                <input name="serviceAttended[2]" type="checkbox" value="11am" <?php if(isset($_POST['serviceAttended'][2])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> > 11:00 AM
            </label>
            <label class="col-2 btn btn-secondary btn-responsive not-active">
                <input name="serviceAttended[3]" type="checkbox" value="other" <?php if(isset($_POST['serviceAttended'][3])) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> > Other
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amit: the pending edit you made: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16104617 was that part of their original code, or did you add that? I am unable to tell right now, since it's not viewable in revisions yet.

Comment: Ok Amit, thanks. The edit was rejected by another member who thought that wasn't.